# How tdo i make a scaling animation from the center?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have a css scaling animation that's this:

```
.DownloadButton:active {
  animation-duration: 0.15s;
  animation-name: clickButton;
  transform-origin: center;
}
@keyframes clickButton {
  from {
    width: 14%;
    font-size:14px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 13.5%;
    padding:0px 2px;
    font-size: 13.5px;
  }
  to {
    width: 14%;
    font-size:14px;
  }
}
```

This is my html:

```
        <a href="...">
            <div class="DownloadButton">
                <p>Click here to download.</p>
            </div>
        </a>
```

but it scales from the top left corner instead of the center. How can I change this?
Also, how to I keep the height of the page consistent when the animation is played?

Comment: It might help to include the relevant HTML and CSS for a [working demonstration](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue.

Comment: Would using transform: scale(calc(13.5 / 14)) work for you instead of animating font size - reason being the transform won't alter other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform-origin: center` in the css rule for the default state.